# Permissions for Oracle function

Tags: sql, oracle

I created the following function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION BANINST1."F_COC_AUTO_AWARD_FILTER" (pidm number) return number
as
return_field number;

cursor get_pidm is
select distinct SHRDGMR.SHRDGMR_PIDM
from SATURN.SHRDGMR SHRDGMR,
     SATURN.SORLCUR SORLCUR,
     SATURN.SORLFOS SORLFOS,
     DWSCHEMA.DAP_AUDIT_DTL@LINKDWTEST
where SORLCUR.SORLCUR_PIDM = SHRDGMR.SHRDGMR_PIDM
     and SORLFOS.SORLFOS_PIDM = SORLCUR.SORLCUR_PIDM
     and SORLCUR.SORLCUR_LEVL_CODE = SHRDGMR.SHRDGMR_LEVL_CODE
     and SORLCUR.SORLCUR_DEGC_CODE = SHRDGMR.SHRDGMR_DEGC_CODE
     and SORLFOS.SORLFOS_TERM_CODE = SORLCUR.SORLCUR_TERM_CODE
     and SHRDGMR.SHRDGMR_PIDM = pidm
     and SHRDGMR.SHRDGMR_DEGS_CODE = 'AW'
     and SORLCUR.SORLCUR_PROGRAM in ('STCC', 'CC')
     and DWSCHEMA.DAP_AUDIT_DTL.DAP_DEGREE in ('CPCC-CDS', 'CC1-CDS', 'CC2-CDS')
     and SORLFOS.SORLFOS_MAJR_CODE <> DWSCHEMA.DAP_AUDIT_DTL.DAP_AUD_VALUE2
     and trim(DWSCHEMA.DAP_AUDIT_DTL.DAP_STU_ID) = (select spriden_id from spriden where spriden_pidm = pidm and spriden_change_ind is null);

begin
   open get_pidm;
   fetch get_pidm into return_field;
   close get_pidm;

return return_field;
end;
/
```

When calling the function in Toad using the BANINST1 user account, the function works normally.

```
SELECT F_COC_AUTO_AWARD_FILTER(293858) FROM DUAL;
```

When calling the function as a different user account (coc_user) the function returns:

```
ORA-00904: "BANINST1"."F_COC_AUTO_AWARD_FILTER": invalid identifier
```

I granted execute permission using the following grant:

```
grant execute on F_COC_AUTO_AWARD_FILTER to coc_user;
```

What else is needed to call the function from the coc_user account?

This is the code that calls the function. It is existing code that I am attempting to modify by adding the call to the function f_coc_auto_award_filter. The function call to f_coc_needs_to_apply on line 7 works fine. The function call that I am trying to add on line 8 returns the error. So the function f_coc_needs_to_apply was configured correctly by the previous developer. I need to understand how to configure the new function f_coc_auto_award_filter.

```
ORA-00904: "BANINST1"."F_COC_AUTO_AWARD_FILTER": invalid identifier
```

```
select rtrim(RAD_PRIMARY_MST.RAD_USER_DEF1) pidm,
RAD_PRIMARY_MST.RAD_ID "StudentID",
       RAD_PRIMARY_MST.RAD_NAME "StudentName",
      (select spbpers_pref_first_name
        from spbpers@test spbpers
        where spbpers_pidm = rtrim(RAD_PRIMARY_MST.RAD_USER_DEF1)) Student_Preferred_first_name,
       nvl(baninst1.f_coc_needs_to_apply@test(RAD_PRIMARY_MST.RAD_USER_DEF1),'N') "NeedsToApply",
       nvl(baninst1.f_coc_auto_award_filter@test(RAD_PRIMARY_MST.RAD_USER_DEF1),999) "AwardFilter",
       DAP_AUDIT_DTL.DAP_AUDIT_DATE "AuditDate",
       DAP_AUDIT_DTL.DAP_AUDIT_TIME "AuditTime",
       DAP_AUDIT_DTL.DAP_AUDIT_PCT "Percent",
       DAP_AUDIT_DTL.DAP_AUDIT_ID "AuditID",
       DAP_AUDIT_DTL.DAP_DEGREE "Program",
       DAP_AUDIT_DTL.DAP_AUD_VALUE2 "MajorCode",
       DAP_AUDIT_DTL.DAP_AUD_BLOCK1 "BlockType",
       RAD_PRIMARY_MST.RAD_EMAIL "StudentEmail",
       (select min(m.sorlfos_majr_code)
        from shrdgmr@test, sorlcur@test, sorlfos@test m, sorlfos@test c
        where shrdgmr_pidm = rtrim(RAD_PRIMARY_MST.RAD_USER_DEF1)
        and SHRDGMR_DEGS_CODE = 'AW'
        and sorlcur_pidm = shrdgmr_pidm
        and sorlcur_lmod_code = 'OUTCOME'
        and sorlcur_seqno = m.sorlfos_lcur_seqno
        and sorlcur_pidm = m.sorlfos_pidm
        and m.sorlfos_lfst_code = 'MAJOR'
        and sorlcur_pidm = c.sorlfos_pidm (+)
        and sorlcur_seqno = c.sorlfos_lcur_seqno (+)
        and c.sorlfos_lfst_code (+)= 'CONCENTRATION'
        and SHRDGMR_SEQ_NO = '1') "AW_MajorCode1",
       (select min(m.sorlfos_majr_code)
        from shrdgmr@test, sorlcur@test, sorlfos@test m, sorlfos@test c
        where shrdgmr_pidm = rtrim(RAD_PRIMARY_MST.RAD_USER_DEF1)
        and SHRDGMR_DEGS_CODE = 'AW'
        and sorlcur_pidm = shrdgmr_pidm
        and sorlcur_lmod_code = 'OUTCOME'
        and sorlcur_seqno = m.sorlfos_lcur_seqno
        and sorlcur_pidm = m.sorlfos_pidm
        and m.sorlfos_lfst_code = 'MAJOR'
        and sorlcur_pidm = c.sorlfos_pidm (+)
        and sorlcur_seqno = c.sorlfos_lcur_seqno (+)
        and c.sorlfos_lfst_code (+)= 'CONCENTRATION'
        and SHRDGMR_SEQ_NO = '2') "AW_MajorCode2",
       (select min(m.sorlfos_majr_code)
        from shrdgmr@test, sorlcur@test, sorlfos@test m, sorlfos@test c
        where shrdgmr_pidm = rtrim(RAD_PRIMARY_MST.RAD_USER_DEF1)
        and SHRDGMR_DEGS_CODE = 'AW'
        and sorlcur_pidm = shrdgmr_pidm
        and sorlcur_lmod_code = 'OUTCOME'
        and sorlcur_seqno = m.sorlfos_lcur_seqno
        and sorlcur_pidm = m.sorlfos_pidm
        and m.sorlfos_lfst_code = 'MAJOR'
        and sorlcur_pidm = c.sorlfos_pidm (+)
        and sorlcur_seqno = c.sorlfos_lcur_seqno (+)
        and c.sorlfos_lfst_code (+)= 'CONCENTRATION'
        and SHRDGMR_SEQ_NO = '3') "AW_MajorCode3",
       (select min(m.sorlfos_majr_code)
        from shrdgmr@test, sorlcur@test, sorlfos@test m, sorlfos@test c
        where shrdgmr_pidm = rtrim(RAD_PRIMARY_MST.RAD_USER_DEF1)
        and SHRDGMR_DEGS_CODE = 'AW'
        and sorlcur_pidm = shrdgmr_pidm
        and sorlcur_lmod_code = 'OUTCOME'
        and sorlcur_seqno = m.sorlfos_lcur_seqno
        and sorlcur_pidm = m.sorlfos_pidm
        and m.sorlfos_lfst_code = 'MAJOR'
        and sorlcur_pidm = c.sorlfos_pidm (+)
        and sorlcur_seqno = c.sorlfos_lcur_seqno (+)
        and c.sorlfos_lfst_code (+)= 'CONCENTRATION'
        and SHRDGMR_SEQ_NO = '4') "AW_MajorCode4",
       (select min(m.sorlfos_majr_code)
        from shrdgmr@test, sorlcur@test, sorlfos@test m, sorlfos@test c
        where shrdgmr_pidm = rtrim(RAD_PRIMARY_MST.RAD_USER_DEF1)
        and SHRDGMR_DEGS_CODE = 'AW'
        and sorlcur_pidm = shrdgmr_pidm
        and sorlcur_lmod_code = 'OUTCOME'
        and sorlcur_seqno = m.sorlfos_lcur_seqno
        and sorlcur_pidm = m.sorlfos_pidm
        and m.sorlfos_lfst_code = 'MAJOR'
        and sorlcur_pidm = c.sorlfos_pidm (+)
        and sorlcur_seqno = c.sorlfos_lcur_seqno (+)
        and c.sorlfos_lfst_code (+)= 'CONCENTRATION'
        and SHRDGMR_DEGS_CODE = 'AW'
        and SHRDGMR_SEQ_NO = '5') "AW_MajorCode5",
       (select min(m.sorlfos_majr_code)
        from shrdgmr@test, sorlcur@test, sorlfos@test m, sorlfos@test c
        where shrdgmr_pidm = rtrim(RAD_PRIMARY_MST.RAD_USER_DEF1)
        and SHRDGMR_DEGS_CODE = 'AW'
        and sorlcur_pidm = shrdgmr_pidm
        and sorlcur_lmod_code = 'OUTCOME'
        and sorlcur_seqno = m.sorlfos_lcur_seqno
        and sorlcur_pidm = m.sorlfos_pidm
        and m.sorlfos_lfst_code = 'MAJOR'
        and sorlcur_pidm = c.sorlfos_pidm (+)
        and sorlcur_seqno = c.sorlfos_lcur_seqno (+)
        and c.sorlfos_lfst_code (+)= 'CONCENTRATION'
        and SHRDGMR_SEQ_NO = '6') "AW_MajorCode6",
       (select min(m.sorlfos_majr_code)
        from shrdgmr@test, sorlcur@test, sorlfos@test m, sorlfos@test c
        where shrdgmr_pidm = rtrim(RAD_PRIMARY_MST.RAD_USER_DEF1)
        and SHRDGMR_DEGS_CODE = 'AW'
        and sorlcur_pidm = shrdgmr_pidm
        and sorlcur_lmod_code = 'OUTCOME'
        and sorlcur_seqno = m.sorlfos_lcur_seqno
        and sorlcur_pidm = m.sorlfos_pidm
        and m.sorlfos_lfst_code = 'MAJOR'
        and sorlcur_pidm = c.sorlfos_pidm (+)
        and sorlcur_seqno = c.sorlfos_lcur_seqno (+)
        and c.sorlfos_lfst_code (+)= 'CONCENTRATION'
        and SHRDGMR_SEQ_NO = '7') "AW_MajorCode7",
     (select sorlcur_degc_code||'|'||m.sorlfos_majr_code||'|'||c.sorlfos_majr_code
      from shrdgmr@test, sorlcur@test, sorlfos@test m, sorlfos@test c
      where shrdgmr_pidm = rtrim(RAD_PRIMARY_MST.RAD_USER_DEF1)
        and SHRDGMR_DEGS_CODE = 'AW'
        and sorlcur_pidm = shrdgmr_pidm
        and sorlcur_lmod_code = 'OUTCOME'
       and sorlcur_seqno = m.sorlfos_lcur_seqno
       and sorlcur_pidm = m.sorlfos_pidm
       and m.sorlfos_lfst_code = 'MAJOR'
       and sorlcur_pidm = c.sorlfos_pidm (+)
       and sorlcur_seqno = c.sorlfos_lcur_seqno (+)
       and c.sorlfos_lfst_code (+)= 'CONCENTRATION'
       and rownum = 1) "AA_Awarded",
       f_coc_degree_mapping@test(rtrim(DAP_AUDIT_DTL.DAP_DEGREE@LINKDWTEST),rtrim(DAP_AUDIT_DTL.DAP_AUD_VALUE2@LINKDWTEST)) dw_value,
       trunc(RAD_PRIMARY_MST.RAD_USER_DEF1@LINKDWTEST) pidm
from DWSCHEMA.DAP_AUDIT_DTL@LINKDWTEST,
       DWSCHEMA.RAD_PRIMARY_MST@LINKDWTEST
 where ( RAD_PRIMARY_MST.RAD_ID = DAP_AUDIT_DTL.DAP_STU_ID )
   and ( to_number(rtrim(DAP_AUDIT_DTL.DAP_AUDIT_PCT)) between :parm_LB_Pct_Complete_Range.Low and :parm_LB_Pct_Complete_Range.High
         and DAP_AUDIT_DTL.DAP_AUD_BLOCK1 = 'DEGREE'
  and (case
      when length(trim(translate(RAD_PRIMARY_MST.RAD_USER_DEF1,'0123456789',' '))) is null then nvl(baninst1.f_coc_needs_to_apply@test(trim(RAD_PRIMARY_MST.RAD_USER_DEF1)),'N')
    end)  <> 'Y'
         and DAP_AUDIT_DTL.DAP_AUDIT_ID like 'AB%'
         and DAP_AUDIT_DTL.DAP_AUDIT_DATE =
         ( select Max( DAP_AUDIT_DTL1.DAP_AUDIT_DATE ) "Max_DAP_AUDIT_DATE"
             from DWSCHEMA.DAP_AUDIT_DTL DAP_AUDIT_DTL1
            where DAP_AUDIT_DTL1.DAP_STU_ID = RAD_PRIMARY_MST.RAD_ID ) )
      and f_coc_degree_mapping@test(rtrim(DAP_AUDIT_DTL.DAP_DEGREE),rtrim(DAP_AUDIT_DTL.DAP_AUD_VALUE2))
      not in
     (select sorlcur_degc_code||'|'||m.sorlfos_majr_code||'|'||c.sorlfos_majr_code
      from shrdgmr@test, sorlcur@test, sorlfos@test m, sorlfos@test c
      where shrdgmr_pidm = rtrim(RAD_PRIMARY_MST.RAD_USER_DEF1)
        and SHRDGMR_DEGS_CODE = 'AW'
        and sorlcur_key_seqno = shrdgmr_seq_no
        and sorlcur_pidm = shrdgmr_pidm
        and sorlcur_lmod_code = 'OUTCOME'
       and sorlcur_seqno = m.sorlfos_lcur_seqno
       and sorlcur_pidm = m.sorlfos_pidm
       and m.sorlfos_lfst_code = 'MAJOR'
       and sorlcur_pidm = c.sorlfos_pidm (+)
       and sorlcur_seqno = c.sorlfos_lcur_seqno (+)
       and c.sorlfos_lfst_code (+)= 'CONCENTRATION')
 order by RAD_PRIMARY_MST.RAD_NAME
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you (successfully) issued that grant statement as `baninst1` and still got the same error when calling `select baninst1.f_coc_auto_award_filter(293858) from dual` as `coc_user`?

Comment: Yes, I issued the grant as baninst1:     grant execute on BANINST1.F_COC_AUTO_AWARD_FILTER to coc_user;   I will post the code that calls the function with more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

​I did a DESCRIBE statement on the function that is working and the new function that was not working. I found that a user account had execute permission on the function that worked but did not have execute permission on the new function. I granted execute on the new function which corrected the invalid identifier error.

Answer (score 0):

The user will need access to all the objects that the function uses.  In this case, grant select on all the tables/views and try again.

You may also need to prefix the function with the name of the schema in which it resides, or create a synonym instead.

Comment: Your first statement is incorrect (since it is using default authid). And the error indicates the OP is already including the schema in the call.

Comment: I missed the schema because it wasnt in code blocks.  Edited.  What do you mean it is using default authid?

Comment: By default the procedure has [definer's rights](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-subprograms.html#GUID-41D23DE7-3C07-41CF-962B-F92B696594B5). Plus, the error is from the call not finding the function, it isn't coming from within the function.

Comment: But the coc_user does not have definers rights.  He didnt define the function.  But you are probably right about the error not coming from inside the function.

Comment: How about granting execute with the schema: ```grant execute on BANINST1.F_COC_AUTO_AWARD_FILTER to coc_user```

Comment: The definer's rights refer to the function, not the caller. The caller `coc_user` doesn't need anything except the execute permission. (So it isn't clear why the OP has an issue... my comment on the question is partly wondering if the grant was correct, including on an object in the right schema, and worked; and partly that it doesn't clearly say that it still fails after the grant, though that is obviously implied.)